# Entity class defines non-transient non-serializable instance field price

Tags: java, sonarlint

Below little bit of code showing SONAR bug like :**Class com.sample.Submit defines non-transient non-serializable instance field price**. How can we get rid from this issue.

### Code

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
public class Submit implements Serializable {

    /**
     * serialVersionUID of type long.
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 0L;

    @JsonProperty("billCode")
    private String billCode;

    @JsonProperty("displayName")
    private String displayName;

    @JsonProperty("visible")
    private Boolean visible;

    @JsonProperty("price")
    private Price price;


    public Boolean getVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public void setVisible(Boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }

    public String getBillCode() {
        return billCode;
    }

    public void setBillCode(String billCode) {
        this.billCode = billCode;
    }

    public String getDisplayName() {
        return displayName;
    }

    public void setDisplayName(String displayName) {
        this.displayName = displayName;
    }


    public Price getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public void setPrice(Price price) {
        this.price = price;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Declare your class `Price` serializable as follows:

```
public class Price implements Serializable {
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you actually need the class to be serializable, then every one of its instance members, like Price, needs to be serializable as well.

Consider if you actually need this Submit class to be serializable though. If you are not doing anything that requires storing this or copying it across a network (like putting it in the HTTP session, or saving it on a file system, or putting it in a queue), you may not need the class to be serializable at all, in which the best course to take is to delete the `implements Serializable` from the Submit class.

(Be aware that making the class serializable has nothing to do with using it to generate JSON.)